# ParseException only on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, date, xml-parsing

I tested my app on 5 various phones and this exception occurs only on Samsung Galaxy Nexus:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 19 Feb 2012 14:02:43 +0100" (at offset 0)`

My input string:

```
<pubDate>Sun, 19 Feb 2012 14:02:43 +0100</pubDate>
```

My code:

```
private String getString(Element item, String tag) {

    Element e = (Element) item.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
    return e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ");
String tmpDate = getString(item, "pubDate");
Date pubDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
pubDate = sdf.parse(tmpDate);
```

Is this a problem of Android 4.0 or I made some mistake?

In addition I have a problem with my national signs. I have xml in UTF-8, and I want to display it in WebView. I have UTF-8 encoded html file and it works perfect on all devices except Galaxy Nexus - it display some strange characters instead of my national signs.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: if the emulator runs fine the problem is NOT with 4.0 or 4.0.3 version but with nexus impl. did u check the emulator to see it's working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that the Nexus has a different locale set by default. Try using the

```
SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
```

variant of the constructor to explicitly set the locale you expect in your date string.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it as soon as I have an access to device.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great for another phone with the same problem :)